# Flex components for JSF

Tags: apache-flex, jsf, icefaces, woodstock

It would make sense to use Flex components with JSF, but searching around I can't find something mainstream. At least not as mainstream as ICEFaces, Woodstock and the other JSF components.

Answer (score 0):

JSF -- which produces (X)HTML -- isn't run in the same framework as Flex, which uses flash on the client.

While it would be possible to embed a .swf within a JSF component, and reuse that component, it isn't possible to -- say -- have an mx:Panel and then put an h:inputText inside that.